# Getstream.io throws exception when using the "to" field

Tags: hashtag, getstream-io

I have two flat Feed Groups, `main`, the primary news feed, and `main_topics`.

I can make a post to either one successfully.

But when I try to 'cc' the other using the `to` field, like, `to: ["main_topics:donuts"]` I get:

```
code: 17
detail: "You do not have permission to do this, you got this error because there are no policies allowing this request on this application. Please consult the documentation https://getstream.io/docs/"
duration: "0.16ms"
exception: "NotAllowedException"
status_code: 403
```

Log:

> The request didn't have the right permissions or autorization. Please check our docs about how to sign requests.

We're generating user tokens server-side, and the token works to read and write to both groups without `to`.

```
// on server
stream_client.user(user.user_id).create({
  name: user.name,
  username: user.username,
});
```

Post body:

```
actor: "SU:5f40650ad9b60a00370686d7"
attachments: {images: [], files: []}
foreign_id: "post:1598391531232"
object: "Newsfeed"
text: "Yum #donuts"
time: "2020-08-25T14:38:51.232"
to: ["main_topics:donuts", "main_topics:all"]
verb: "post"
```

The docs show an example with `to: ['team:barcelona', 'match:1'],` and say you need to create the feed groups in the panel, but mention nothing about setting up specific permissions to use this feature.

Any idea why this would happen? Note that I'm trying to create the new topics (donuts, all) which don't exist when this post is made. However, the docs don't specify that feeds need to be explicitly created first - maybe that's the missing piece?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven’t already tried creating the feed first, then try that. Besides that, the default permissions restrict a user from posting on another’s feed.  I think it’s acceptable to do this if it’s a notification feed but not user or timeline.

You can email the getstream support to change the default permissions because these are not manageable from the dashboard.

Or you can do this call server side as an admin permissions.